# Как убрать модальное окно на сайте кнопкой "назад" на телефоне?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

На сайте есть модальные окна, которые хорошо работают на ПК-версии, но на мобильной есть проблема. Если на сайте открыто попап-окно, и нажать на кнопку "Назад", то окно не скроется (как хотелось бы), а сайт просто закроется. Это максимально неудобно и проблематично.

Было предложение добавить пустой якорь в строку поиска при открытии окна. Но если нажать "Назад", то тогда якорь убирается, сайт скроллится вверх, а окно остаётся. Может, есть способ как-то допилить этот вариант? Или есть другие решения?

Буду благодарен, если поможете. Спасибо.

https://soffit.info/

Comment: Воспользуйтесь History API браузера, и пуште туда какой-нибудь урл при открытии модалки. Потом подпишитесь на изменения в истории, и смотрите, когда урл модалки вылетит и закрывайте окно

Answer (score 0):

Можно переопределить кнопку «Назад» с помощью `addEventListener`. Логика примерно следующая:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton',() => {
    // Проверяем, есть ли на модальном окне .visible
    // Убираем .visible с модального окнаа
});
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример? Как это реализовать?